# What does omg in the package name org.omg stand for

Tags: java, corba

What does OMG stand for with reference to the [CORBA API's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/package-summary.html).

Comment: Can you give the reason for the negative vote?

Comment: I downvoted because this question is off topic at best.  Further it doesn't matter why someone named a package a certain way and is at best a bit of trivium

Comment: The link you provided took me to a page with a "How is Babby Formed" level of engagement.

Comment: The link was http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_OMG's_CORBA And I changed the question. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Delete the question yourself and the downvotes won't count against you.

Comment: Well I cant delete the question as it has an answer that has been accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stands for the [Object Management Group](http://www.omg.org).